# Cannot display blob data from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I am trying to display a BLOB data from a database using the PHP code below, but it doesn't load, in the place of the picture I can only see the question mark (absence). What did I do wrong? I'm new to PHP btw.

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `blog_posts` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<article>"; 
        echo    "<header>".$row["title"]."</header>"; 
        echo    "<div class='post-content'>";   
        echo        "<div class='post-image'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row["picture"])." width='290' height='290'></div>"; 
        echo        "<div class='post-text'>".$row["body"]."</div>"; 
        echo    "</div>"; 
        echo    "<div class='post-footer'>".$row["likes_number"]."  likes ".$row["comments_number"]."  comments"; 
        echo    "</div>";
        echo "</article>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: How are you storing the image in the DB? If you look at your page html source, what do you see?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are missing a closing single quote after the src of the  tag

add ' after src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row["picture"])." or try this 
`src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['picture']).'"`

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that, but thank you! It works now.

Comment: Always happy to help